# How to assigned a different session variable to different buttons

Tags: php, session, variables, button

I have a index.php file with the following code where I get the names of the cities stored in my Database print all the cities and print a button for each of the cities. Example: having the cities in my database (London, New York and San Francisco) I will have something like:

London     --> Button

New York     --> Button

San Franciso     --> Button

```
 <?PHP
    while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $nameofcity = $myrow[cityname];

    echo $nameofcity;
    $_SESSION['variabletopass'] = $nameofcity;
    echo'<form name"formname" method="post" action="results.php">';
    echo'<input type="submit" name="submit" value="See City">';
    echo'</form>';   
   }
?>
```

Then I have my results.php that is going to open when clicking in the button.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$var_nameofcity = $_SESSION['variabletopass'];
//Here I look in my database for info base on $var_nameofcity
// something like select description from cities where city = $var_nameofcity
//And I print the info
echo  $var_nameofcity;  
echo 'Here it goes the Picture of the city'; 
echo 'description';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is: Since the

```
    $_SESSION['variabletopass'] = $nameofcity;
    echo'<form name"formname" method="post" action="results.php">';
    echo'<input type="submit" name="submit" value="See City">';
    echo'</form>';
```

is within a While, the $_SESSION['variabletopass'] is going to get only the last vale, so not matter which button I press it is going to open my last city (In the example: San Francisco).

How can I do, so the variable passed ($_SESSION['variabletopass'] = $nameofcity;) when pressing a button is the one associated to the correspondent city?

Thank you much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the city name to a hidden input in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="<?php echo $nameofcity; ?>" />
```

Then when you post the form, that city is available in $_POST global as an index named the same as your hidden input:

```
<?php $nameofcity = $_POST['city']; ?>
```

Obviously, keep in mind that you would want some security checks on reading the $_POSTed input to keep script injection and possible SQL injection at a minimum.

Comment: Thanks!!! This is great!!! Thanks, the solution I was looking for. I just having a little extra problem, I'm trying to actually print the input with PHP and I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong:  `echo '<input type="hidden" name="city" value=" ' $nameofcity ' " >';`

Comment: But if I do: echo `'<input type="hidden" name="city" value="London" >';` then it works

Comment: ok, I got it: for some reason the " ' needs to be in a different order: echo "<input type='hidden' name='city' value=' $nameofcity ' />";  and works. THANKS

Comment: You are relying on PHP's double quote syntax, where variables called by name inside a double quote escaped string are printed.  When using single quotes to encase a string, you need to use the concatenation operator (.) to insert a variable: echo 'hello' . $world . '!; vs echo "Hello $world!";